# Is it possible to get the specific part of a regex that matched the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex, with a lot of parts.
example:

> var match = Regex.match("variablestring","(variabe|variables|stringvariable|strink|variablestring|varstrings)");

My real example has a lot more with a lot more subtle differences.

I need a way to know which part of my regex got a hit.
Like in this case = "(variabe|variables|stringvariable|strink|**variablestring**|varstrings)"
I want Regex or a diff part of code to tell me that |variablestring| was the part of the regex that got a hit.
i dont care that much about the output itself, i want to know what part of the REGEX was the reason i got a match
Is there a way?

i have looked at different ways, and looked for some method or property but i havent found anything specific that could help me, anyone any ideas?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times on this site, but basically what you want to do is to put the longer terms in the alternation first, i.e. use: `(variablestring|variables|variable|stringvariable|string|varstrings)`

Comment: no, that is not what i want, i want to get the specific regex part that got the hit on my string

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a concrete example including inputs, pattern, and expected outputs. Including your attempt would be helpful as well.

Comment: `'one' -match '(?:(?<matched_one>one)|(?<matched_two>two))'`

Comment: interesting, what is this?

Comment: Sorry - posted my comment as PowerShell - see answer for C#

Comment: Ps. `variablestring` didn't get hit, as `variable` matched first, so the other options were never assessed.  If you want to match a full word you'd need to test `^variablestring$` (i.e. `^` = start of line, `$` = end of line; so means the whole string has to exist between these.  To do that for all words: `"^(?:(?<variable>variabe)|(?<variables>variables)|(?<stringvariable>stringvariable)|(?<strink>strink)|(?<variablestring>variablestring)|(?<varstrings>varstrings))$";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should do the trick.

```cs
void Main()
{
    // note: the names can differ from the matched value; I kept them the same so it's obvious which value they relate to
    var pattern = "(?<variable>variabe)|(?<variables>variables)|(?<stringvariable>stringvariable)|(?<strink>strink)|(?<variablestring>variablestring)|(?<varstrings>varstrings)";

    var stringToTest = "variablestring";
    var match = Regex.Match(stringToTest,pattern);

    var nameOfMatchGroup = 
        match
        .Groups
        .Cast<Group>()
        .Where(x => x.Success && (x.Name != "0"))
        .First()
        .Name;

    Console.WriteLine(nameOfMatchGroup);
}
```

The regex pattern is `"(?<variable>variabe)|(?<variables>variables)|(?<stringvariable>stringvariable)|(?<strink>strink)|(?<variablestring>variablestring)|(?<varstrings>varstrings)`.

This uses something called Named Capture groups: `(?<name>pattern)` where `name` is the name of the group and `pattern` is the regex pattern of the contents of that group.  For more see [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions)

I've then used Linq to filter through the various captures in the group to find the one which matched (`Success = true`), ignoring the one with `Name = 0` as that's the whole expression, rather than the child named capture group.
I then take the first of the items that match those conditions (in this case there will only be one, as though multiple patterns match they're delimitted by pipes; so once one matches other possible matches in that set are ignored as that part of the string has already been tested), then get the `Name` of that capture group.

The `Cast` statement is because `GroupCollection` (the type of `match`) doesn't implement `IEnumerable`; so to use Linq over it we first need to convert it.